# Simple inventory SQL query not listing all products MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, inventory, stock

So I have this simple SELECT query:
[design view of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJqFc.png)

```
SELECT tblProducts.product_ID, Sum(tblIntakes.intake_QTY)-Sum(tblExits.exit_QTY) AS Stock
FROM (tblProducts INNER JOIN tblExits ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblExits.product_ID) 
  INNER JOIN tblIntakes ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblIntakes.product_ID
GROUP BY tblProducts.product_ID;
```

It doesn't list all the products. It only list those products that had an intake AND an exit. This isn't useful since I would like to know the stock level of all the products.

This is what I get from the query:

```
| product_ID | Stock |
| 1          | 4     |
```

This is what I wan't to get

```
| product_ID | Stock |
| 1          | 4     |
| 2          | 10    |
| 3          | 0     |
```

This shouldn't be much complicated but I'm new to access and SQL and it's giving me an headache. Any help would be greatly appreciated

These are the records:

products

```
| product_ID | product_Name |
| 1          | Pencil       |
| 2          | Book         |
| 3          | Marker       |
```

intakes

```
| intake_ID | intake_Date | product_ID  | intake_QTY |
| 1         | 20/07/2017  | 1           | 10         |
| 2         | 20/07/2017  | 2           | 10         |
```

exits

```
| exit_ID | exit_Date  | product_ID | exit_QTY |
| 1       | 21/07/2017 | 1          | 6        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `left join` and `nz()`

```
SELECT tblProducts.product_ID,
       nz(Sum(tblIntakes.intake_QTY), 0) - nz(Sum(tblExits.exit_QTY)) AS Stock
FROM (tblProducts LEFT JOIN
      tblExits
      ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblExits.product_ID
     ) LEFT JOIN
      tblIntakes
      ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblIntakes.product_ID
GROUP BY tblProducts.product_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Unfortunately I didn't know about  "outer joins". Now at least I know they exist. Thanks

Comment: What if each intake would have a provider associated with it? Lets say I add a column for intakes called provider_ID and the same for exits

How could I list the inventory discriminating the provider? So I can treat the same product_ID but from a different provider as a different product?

Comment: I tried with this query but it gives an ambiguity error

`SELECT tblProducts.product_ID, 
 tblProviders.provider, 
 Nz(Sum(tblIntakes.intake_QTY),0)-
 Nz(Sum(tblExits.exit_QTY)) AS Stock`

`FROM ((tblProducts LEFT JOIN tblExits ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblExits.product_ID)
 LEFT JOIN tblIntakes ON tblProducts.product_ID = tblIntakes.product_ID) 
 LEFT JOIN tblProviders ON (tblExits.provider_ID = tblProviders.provider_ID) 
 AND (tblIntakes.provider_ID = tblProviders.provider_ID)`

`GROUP BY tblProducts.product_ID, tblProviders.provider;`

Comment: @SantiagoBarclay . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.